# How to read WKT files with Python

Tags: python, software-recommendations, well-known-text

I want to read a WKT file with the path "path.wkt" to work with it in Python.

The file has the following format:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((8.670759751629118 47.68652606800615, 8.666622492582087 47.68642950703099, 8.665003792099743 47.68663598638347, 8.661069658619452 47.69075902436904)))
```

Do I need a special library to do that?

Comment: What have you find, what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried with Shapely but this library is only suitable for working with wkt data but not for reading it from a file.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hi, I want to read the wkt file in Python so that I can work with it later with the library Shapely. I tried with open('path') but it is not recognized as a wkt archive

Comment: With exactly that geometry you will have troubles with any WKT library because the geometry is not a valid multipolygon. The error is `Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring`.

Comment: It is true, but by the original archive ist the area closed. What I wrote in my question was only an example.

Comment: Open your wkt file, and read it into a string with Python, then pass the string for https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.from_wkt.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file using csv module and create a geometry with shapely.
But your WKT is invalid. It has to start and end in the same point.

```
import csv
import shapely

file = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/untitled.wkt"

data = []
with open(file, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        data.append(line[0])
       
for wkt in data:
    shapely.wkt.loads(wkt)
    #GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

If I add the first coordinate pair to the end:

```
wkt_fixed = 'MULTIPOLYGON (((8.670759751629118 47.68652606800615, 8.666622492582087 47.68642950703099, 8.665003792099743 47.68663598638347, 8.661069658619452 47.69075902436904, 8.670759751629118 47.68652606800615)))'
geometry = shapely.wkt.loads(wkt_fixed)
# geometry.is_valid
# True
```